# Javascript Promise, It behaves strange

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a question and I think, it is really easy for some of you guys but I do not understand why Javascript behave like this. **The code below console logs, 'c, a, b, d' in order. Why is that?**

```js
var doSomething = function() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res();
  });
}

var doSomethingElse = function(par) {
  console.log(par);
}

doSomething().then(function() {
  return doSomethingElse('a');
});

doSomething().then(function() {
  doSomethingElse('b');
});

doSomething().then(doSomethingElse('c'));
doSomething().then(() => doSomethingElse('d'));
```

Comment: your second last line calls the function instead of passing it to `then`. The others just execute in order, however you shouldn't assume any specific order since the promise chains are all unrelated.

Comment: doSomethingElse('c') is calling the function and using what it returns in then. Since it does not return anything it is basically `doSomething().then(undefined);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `doSomething().then(doSomethingElse('c'));` doSomethingElse is executed immediately
If you delay the promise response you will see the time difference.

```js
var doSomething = function() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(()=> res(),3000);
  });
}

var doSomethingElse = function(par) {
  console.log(par);
}

doSomething().then(function() {
  return doSomethingElse('a');
});

doSomething().then(function() {
  doSomethingElse('b');
});

doSomething().then(doSomethingElse('c'));
doSomething().then(() => doSomethingElse('d'));
```